# Rails routing: override the action name in a resource/member block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec2

I know how to do this with `match` but I really want to do it in the resource block. Here's what I have (simplified):

```
resources :stories do
  member do
    'put' collaborator
    'delete' collaborator
  end
end
```

I am looking for a way to allow the same action name in the URL but have different entry points in the controller. At the moment I've got in my controller:

```
# PUT /stories/1/collaborator.json
def add_collaborator
  ...
end

# DELETE /stories/1/collaborator.json
def remove_collaborator
  ...
end
```

So I tried this:

```
resources :stories do
  member do
    'put' collaborator, :action => 'add_collaborator'
    'delete' collaborator, :action => 'remove_collaborator'
  end
end
```

but this didn't seem to work when I wrote an rspec unit test:

```
describe "PUT /stories/1/collaborator.json" do
  it "adds a collaborator to the story" do
    story = FactoryGirl.create :story
    collaborator = FactoryGirl.create :user

    xhr :put, :collaborator, :id => story.id, :collaborator_id => collaborator.id

    # shoulds go here...
end
```

end

I get this error:

```
Finished in 0.23594 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure, 1 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/stories_controller_spec.rb:78 # StoriesController PUT    
  /stories/1/collaborator.json adds a collaborator to the story
```

I'm assuming this error is because the way I'm trying to define my routes is incorrect...any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the following better?

```
resources :stories do
 member do
   put 'collaborator' => 'controller_name#add_collaborator' 
   delete 'collaborator' => 'controller_name#remove_collaborator'
 end
end
```

You should also check your routes by launching in a terminal:

```
$ rake routes > routes.txt
```

And opening the generated routes.txt file to see what routes are generated from your routes.rb file.

Comment: This made the routes show up correctly in the rake routes output and for that I am eternally grateful :) I'm still getting the rspec failure but now at least I know it's not that my routes are broken.  thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, maybe I can help you further with your rspec failure?

Comment: that would be awesome. I tried doing a much simpler example using a get route and naming it with :path. From the browser it totally works. When I do `xhr :get, :test_path` it doesn't find the route, with the same basic message as in my original post.

Comment: on further exploration everything works if I use the actual action name in the rspec test: `xhr :put, :add_collaborator, ...`. I'm thinking that I should test that the route mapping works in a routes test and let it go at that :)

Comment: What do you have around the 78th line of your stories_controller_spec.rb file? Is it what you're already showing in your post? I think this error is related to the rspec task but not sure. That's great if it works. Let me know if you need further assistance, I'll try to do my best to help you. :)